# download PDF file from external website with inappbrowser ionic cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm working on android app and iOS, I use Ionic

I want to open external link with InAppBrowser and allow the user to download file from a link inside this site...

But when I click on download link inside this site, nothing really happens...

We are trying to download PDF file from external website and open into the mobile pdfviewer

Comment: InApp Browser won't work for opening pdf file. Try other way like download internally and open with system pfd viewer etc.

Comment: We did it https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer as you can use blob directly to generate your pdf and use it in the viewer. The InAppBrowser can't open pdf.